# Run and execute 2 powershell scripts sequentialy

Tags: powershell

I'm tryng to run the following ps1 script

```html
PowerShell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://server/file1.ps1','file1.ps1');Start-Process 'file1.ps1'
PowerShell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://server/file2.ps1','file2.ps1');Start-Process 'file2.ps1'
```

but I'm getting no output

How can I do download and execute file1.ps1 and after that file2.ps1

Thank you

Comment: The reason folks are down-voting you is that this is a very basic intro to Powershell stuff. PowerShell will not assume everything for you. You have to tell it how to start and where stuff is to run and what to do with it. Why are you starting powershell.exe twice? You are not seeing anything because this can happen fast and you are not telling PowerShell to wait and show you results. You should never randomly download and run files from anyone/anywhere unless you are absolutely sure you know what it is doing, or deal with and accept the risks of running it. Ther are lots of web examples.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to start PowerShell twice.

Loops, workflows, et al, is how you run actions multiple times.

> [Microsoft TechNet PowerShell Loops](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4542.powershell-loops.aspx)

Create a single script, call PowerShell.exe once to run the script.
All PowerShell startup switches are in the help files

```
powershell /?
```

***Example Script:***

```
'https://server/file1.ps1','https://server/file1.ps1' |
ForEach {
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $url       = $PSitem
    $filename  = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($url)
    $file      = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\$filename"
    $webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)
    Unblock-File -Path $file 
    Start-Process $file -Wait
}
```

Please spend some time getting up to speed on PowerShell and using PowerShell with web resources. Youtube has plenty of videos to learn from and there are tons of blogs on the topic.

• YouTube
Search with these to get going…

> ['Beginning PowerShell'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27Advanced%20PowerShell%27)
>
> ['Intermediate PowerShell'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27Advanced%20PowerShell%27)
>
> ['Advanced PowerShell'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27Advanced%20PowerShell%27)

• Article(s)
['3 Ways to download files PowerShell'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=3%20ways%20to%20download%20files%20powershell&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=3%20ways%20to%20download%20files%20powershell&sc=1-35&sk=&cvid=260B3590DA1F400D9A41FDCB088F1251)

Don't stress yourself out by guessing.